# limit of form "$∞ \cdot 0$"

Tags: analysis, limits

I am trying to formally prove that limit of $2^n\sin(π/2^n)$ as $n$ approaches infinity is $π$. Generally I can tell limit of each term of product of $∞$ and $0$ respectively, but am little confused how to make use of these facts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac{\sin(\pi/2^n)}{\pi/2^n}\to1$ when $n\to\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Using the well known limit for $\frac{\sin{x}}{x} \xrightarrow{x \to 0} 1$

$$\lim_{n \to\infty} 2^n \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right) = \lim_{n \to\infty} \pi \frac{2^n}{\pi} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right) = \pi \lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^n}} = \pi \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin(z)}{z} = \pi$$

where $z= \frac{\pi}{2^n}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(z)/z\to1$ when $z\to0$. What does that mean if $z=\pi/2^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Recall from elementary geometry that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\cos(x)\le \sin(x)\le x \tag 1$$

for $0\le x\le \pi/2$.  Therefore, letting $x=\pi/2^n$ in $(1)$ and multiplying through by $2^n$ reveals

$$\pi \cos(\pi/2^n)\le 2^n\sin(\pi/2^n)\le \pi$$

Applying the squeeze theorem yields the limit of interest.